# Every other rmarkdown render fails

Tags: r-markdown

I created a template in Rmd that grabs some sales data and according to an input given it creates a specific report for those sales. The objective is to automate report generation every month.

The function is as follows:

```
create_report_avaliacao <- function(infoprex,vendas,colaboradores,month, year){
  rmarkdown::render(input = "template.Rmd",
                  params = list(  infoprex= infoprex,
                                  vendas= vendas,
                                  operador= colaboradores,
                                  excluir= "Dr Miguel"),
                  envir = new.env(),
                  clean = TRUE,
                  output_file = paste0("Avaliacao_desempenho_mensal_",colaboradores,"_",month,"_",year,".html"),
                  output_format = "html_document")
}
```

To automate the reports I run the render inside a loop:

```
    for(i in 1:length(colaboradores)){
  create_report_avaliacao(ficheiro_infoprex,ficheiro_vendas,colaboradores[i], month, year)
}
```

Whenever it is ran every other report creates an empty html file while on the other half it runs fine.

I've ran them with different inputs to see if it was something codewise on the template but it runs fine with every input, just fails half the time like clockwork, independent of what I through at it.

Any ideia what the problem might be?

EDIT:

Just to provide more info: whenever it fails it outputs

```
processing file: template.Rmd
  |                                                                                                                                          |   0%
output file: template.knit.md

/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS template.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc7ffd6cbf7e36.html --lua-filter /home/andre/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /home/andre/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --variable bs3=TRUE --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --variable toc_float=1 --variable toc_selectors=h1,h2,h3 --variable toc_collapsed=1 --variable toc_smooth_scroll=1 --variable toc_print=1 --template /home/andre/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=yeti --include-in-header /tmp/Rtmp3tVKiK/rmarkdown-str7ffd707fe538.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' 
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Defaulting to 'template_avaliacao_mensal.knit' as the title.
  To specify a title, use 'title' in metadata or --metadata title="...".

Output created: Avaliacao_desempenho_mensal_Solange Sousa_12_2020.html
```